# MySql Join in two tables using two different join statement in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Whether the following join is valid in MySQL or not

```
$this->db->select('A.plan_prepared_by,A.approval_date, U.display_name');
$this->db->from('A');
$this->db->where('plan_id', $planid );
$this->db->join('U','U.id=A.approval_user_id','left');
$this->db->join('U','U.username =A.plan_prepared_by','left');
```

Comment: what happened when you tried?

Comment: if it's not working as you expected. Have you tried to use `Group By` and `Having`

Comment: Are your tables really called A, and U? That doesn't make any sense!

Comment: @Jens Ahlsten Herlevsen - It is not the original table names, it's just the pseudo names. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it like this by putting aliases

```
$select =   array(
                    'A.plan_prepared_by',
                    'A.approval_date',
                    'UL.display_name'
);
$where  =   array(
                    'plan_id'   =>  $planid
);

$this->db->select($select);
$this->db->from('A');
$this->db->where($where);
$this->db->join('U AS UL','UL.id = A.approval_user_id','left');
$this->db->join('U AS UR','UR.username = A.plan_prepared_by','left');
```